# jquery tabs navigation menu

Tags: jquery, tabs, navigation

I just started learning jQuery, so I'm a beginner.

My goal is to create a tabs navigation menu. I made this code here:

```
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();


$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var h_active = $(this).attr("rel"); 
  $("#"+h_active).fadeIn(500);      

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(".v_tabs").removeClass("v_active");
  $(".v_tabs[rel^='"+h_active+"']").addClass("v_active");

});
```

but reading on the internet, I realized that it is not really the best.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zPavan/ESe7k/1/) is an example to view the entire code:

How can I add a fadeOut transition?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selectorForElement").fadeOut(1000); //fadeout for 1 second
```